# How to Insert Value That is Not Repeating in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

How can I insert a value that is not repeating? I'm working on a time-keeping system, right now the problem is when I add time and add time again that is the same day the time is repeating. How can I insert time that doesn't repeat even when I add the time again? Thank you so much here is my code. Is it possible to do that?

My current data is this, and my final output must be that `employee_no 10310` must only be one and not repeating data. It should not repeat and not insert `id 3`.

[image]

**Controller**

```php
public function insertSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $employeeTimeSet = new Schedule;
    $employeeTimeSet->employee_no = $request->input('hidEmployeeno');
    $employeeTimeSet->last_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeLast');
    $employeeTimeSet->first_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst');
    $employeeTimeSet->date_today = $request->input('dateToday');
    $employeeTimeSet->time_in = $request->input('timeIn');
    $employeeTimeSet->time_out = $request->input('timeOut');
    $employeeTimeSet->save();

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Employee Time Set!',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect('/admin/employeemaintenance/createSchedule')->with($notification, 'Employee Time Set');
}
```

**View**

```php
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'Admin\EmployeeFilemController@insertSchedule', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <small>Employee No. and Name:</small>
        <b><i> {{ $employee->employee_no }} : {{ $employee->last_name }}, {{ $employee->first_name }}</i></b>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeno" value='<?php echo $employee->employee_no ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeLast" value='<?php echo $employee->last_name ?>'>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidEmployeeFirst" value='<?php echo $employee->first_name ?>'>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>DATE TODAY</th>
        <th>TIME IN</th>
        <th>TIME OUT</th>
        <th>ACTION</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b><?php  echo date("F-d-Y");  ?></b></td>
        <!---Date Hidden-->
        <input type="hidden" name="dateToday" value='<?php echo date("F-d-Y") ?>'>
        <td><input type="time" name="timeIn" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
        <td><input type="time" name="timeOut" class="form-control col-md-10"></td>
        <td> {{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-clock">&nbsp;&nbsp;SET TIME</i>',['type' => 'submit','class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm',  'style'=>"display: inline-block;"])}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Database Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schedules', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('employee_no')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('date_today')->nullable();
        $table->string('time_in')->nullable();
        $table->string('time_out')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you update the question with currently inserted value and your expected value?

Comment: @Eisenheim , sir i've edited my question could you please see it ? thanks

Comment: What combination needs to be unique: `employee_no`+ `date_today`? or also with `time_in`/`time_out`?

Comment: @HCK yes sir you right ! , i also need the time_in and time_out because when the user set the time in it must not be double also , you are right sir.

Comment: "Time In" is different for row id 1 and row id 3. Which one you need to keep? Is row 3 has wrong time in data?

Comment: Solution could be `updateOrCreate()` method. Study that subject, it's in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent).

Answer (score 0):

In your migration, update this

```
$table->string('employee_no')->nullable();
```

to this:

```
$table->string('employee_no')->unique();
```

Comment: what if the admin will input time on the nextday? then empoyee_no wil never be input again?

Comment: `My current data is this, and my final output must be that employee_no 10310 must only be one and not repeating data. It should not repeat and not insert id 3.`. I thought you wanted similar employee_no to be prevented. 10310 will never be inserted again. But other employee_no will

Comment: ohh sir  it must have confused you , sorry for that .. what I meant was that the day is updating every day automatically so the admin needs to input time every day. that is how what i meant for that and also for the employee that is needed to be only one value and not repeating  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you could improve this in other aspect of your site, but given that we don't know your use case.. this should do the trick:

```
public function insertSchedule(Request $request)
{
    $schedule = Schedule::where('employee_no', $request->input('hidEmployeeno'))
                ->where('date_today', $request->input('dateToday'))
                ->where('time_in', $request->input('timeIn'))
                ->where('time_out', $request->input('timeOut'))
                ->first();

    if( ! $schedule)
    {
        $employeeTimeSet = new Schedule;
        $employeeTimeSet->employee_no = $request->input('hidEmployeeno'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->last_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeLast'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->first_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->date_today = $request->input('dateToday'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->time_in = $request->input('timeIn'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->time_out = $request->input('timeOut'); 
        $employeeTimeSet->save();

        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Employee Time Set!',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'The entry already exists!',
            'alert-type' => 'warning'
        );
    }


return redirect('/admin/employeemaintenance/createSchedule')
           ->with($notification, 'Employee Time Set');
```

}

Comment: sir im not pretty sure why it didnt work but could we please check our code on your and on my end? thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [firstOrNew()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

```
$employeeTimeSet = Schedule::firstOrNew(['employee_no' => $request->input('hidEmployeeno'), 'date_today' => $request->input('dateToday')]);
$employeeTimeSet->last_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeLast');
$employeeTimeSet->first_name = $request->input('hidEmployeeFirst');
$employeeTimeSet->time_in = $request->input('timeIn');
$employeeTimeSet->time_out = $request->input('timeOut');
$employeeTimeSet->save();
```